# Can I add more than one period to perform a sync in Android syncAdapter?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I'm implementing a `SyncAdapter` and I need to synchronize a few times in a day but I also need the `onPerformSync` trigger a synchronization at midnight.

```java
ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, URIBuilder.AUTHORITY, 1);

Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, false);
extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_DO_NOT_RETRY, false);
extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, false);

ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account,
    URIBuilder.AUTHORITY,
    extras, 15000);

ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, URIBuilder.AUTHORITY, true);
ContentResolver.requestSync(account, URIBuilder.AUTHORITY, extras);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. By using [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html); once the server data changed the server will send a push notification of what has been changed. Or you can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html);

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,
            MyBoradcastReciever.class);

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, uid, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, sender);
```

---

In BroadcastReceiver

```
new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            TriggerRefresh(); 

        }
    };
```

---

```
 public static void TriggerRefresh() {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    // Disable sync backoff and ignore sync preferences. In other
    // words...perform sync NOW!
    b.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
    b.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
    ContentResolver.requestSync(LNTAccountService.GetAccount(), // Sync
                                                                // account
            CONTENT_AUTHORITY, // Content authority
            b); // Extras
}
```